# Custom input component has required error even after being filled

Tags: angular

I've created a custom input component by implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. Then, I put it on a form with required validation by setting the `required` property to `true`. However, it's giving me a "required" error even when the input is filled - in other words, `model.errors.invalid` is true even after I fill the field.

A reproducible example is available on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9p4udk?file=src/app/input-password/input-password.component.html), but here is some of the code.

## Component

```js
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-password',
  templateUrl: 'input-password.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputPasswordComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class InputPasswordComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange = (value: any) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  private _password = '';
  private passwordIsVisible = false;

  get password() {
    return this._password;
  }

  set password(newPassword: string) {
    this._password = newPassword;
  }

  get buttonLabel() {
    return this.passwordIsVisible ? 'Hide password' : 'Show password';
  }

  get inputType() {
    return this.passwordIsVisible ? 'text' : 'password';
  }

  togglePasswordVisibility() {
    this.passwordIsVisible = !this.passwordIsVisible;
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.password = value;
    this.onChange(this.password);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

## Template

```html
<input [type]="inputType" [(ngModel)]="password" (blur)="onTouched()" />
<button (click)="togglePasswordVisibility()" style="cursor: pointer">
  {{ buttonLabel }}
</button>
```

## Form

```
<app-input-password
  ngModel
  #model="ngModel"
  [required]="true"
></app-input-password>

<p>Touched? {{ model.touched }}</p>
<p>Required error? {{ model.errors.required }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the `onChange` in the setter instead of of `writeValue`, that should solve your issue as now the new value will actually be set, it didnt before and thus remained as required (as no value). Also remember to use optional chaining in displaying your error, otherwise it will throw a browser console error.

So remove the `onChange` from `writeValue`  and set it in the setter:

```
set password(newPassword: string) {
  this._password = newPassword;
  this.onChange(newPassword);
}
```

The optional chaining:

```
<p>Required error? {{ model?.errors?.required }}</p>
```

Your forked **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-avbwgt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**